# Tensor flow failing to load on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu, keras

A piece of code runs on my local machine but throws the following error when running on a remote server. How do I identify the cause of the problem?

Have not encountered such problems before so want to know how to proceed to debug such errors.

```
 Starting the execution.. Using TensorFlow backend. Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/biplavc/anaconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>


    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File "/home/biplavc/anaconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "/home/biplavc/anaconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)   File "/home/biplavc/anaconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)   File "/home/biplavc/anaconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec) ImportError: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.23' not found (required by /home/biplavc/anaconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 14, in <module>
    from network import *   File "/home/biplavc/data/AoI/UAV_Age/network.py", line 11, in <module>
    from utils import  *   File "/home/biplavc/data/AoI/UAV_Age/utils.py", line 2, in <module>
    from keras.losses import mean_squared_error   File "/home/biplavc/anaconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils   File "/home/biplavc/anaconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import conv_utils   File "/home/biplavc/anaconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .. import backend as K   File "/home/biplavc/anaconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *   File "/home/biplavc/anaconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf   File "/home/biplavc/anaconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import   File "/home/biplavc/anaconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow   File "/home/biplavc/anaconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg) ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/biplavc/anaconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File "/home/biplavc/anaconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "/home/biplavc/anaconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)   File "/home/biplavc/anaconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)   File "/home/biplavc/anaconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec) ImportError: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.23' not found (required by /home/biplavc/anaconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so)


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: Take a look here: ImportError: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.23' The problem is that glibc in that server is just too old, but do not try to update it (you can break the whole system).

Comment: Can this be corrected inside of a conda environment ?

Comment: No, it is a native library issue

Comment: If you have a container runner on your server, like `singularity` or `docker`, then you can use the script within one of the TensorFlow Docker containers. That will solve the glibc issue because the container will have its own glibc that is compatible with tensorflow.